# Get all grandchildren holonym for a grandparent hypernym in wordnet

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I would like to create a set of alternative words for a word. The alternative word has to be suitably different so that replacing 'dog' with 'dalmatian' is too similar- I would want to replace 'dog' with 'cat'. Although not infallible, I think I can do this by getting the hypernym for a word and ten that hypernym's hypernym (Ie that grandparent synset) and finally getting all the grandchildren words for that grandparent.

Hopefully this makes sense. In pseudocode it should read

```
for each i as hypernym (synset)
     for each j as i.hypernym
         get all the holonyms for j as s
              for each s get all the holonyms as x
                 print x
```

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn


gflemma_holonym = defaultdict(set)
for ss in wn.all_synsets():
    if ss.part_holonyms() and ss.hypernyms() and ss.hypernyms()[0].hypernyms():
        grandfather = ss.hypernyms()[0].hypernyms()[0] # grandfather concept.
        holonyms = list(chain(*[i.lemma_names() for i in ss.part_holonyms()]))
        for lemma in grandfather.lemma_names():
            gflemma_holonym[lemma].update(holonyms)


print gflemma_holonym[u'edible_nut']
print
print gflemma_holonym[u'geographical_area']
```

[out]:

```
set([u'black_hickory', u'black_walnut', u'Juglans_nigra', u'black_walnut_tree'])

set([u'battlefield', u'fair', u'infield', u'field_of_honor', u'field_of_battle', u'battleground', u'city', u'bowl', u'field', u'stadium', u'funfair', u'outfield', u'diamond', u'urban_area', u'populated_area', u'desert', u'arena', u'carnival', u'baseball_diamond', u'sports_stadium', u'ball_field', u'baseball_field'])
```

Please note that wordnet inventory is limited. Especially when you are looking for relations of concepts/lemma that is so far apart (i.e. from synset's grandfather to synset's holonym)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ether lists or dictionary to do this ( dictionary is more pythonic ). 
for exemple with dictionnary you have something like this :

```
dictionnary={"dog": {"dalmatian","stuff"}, "singer": {"rihanna","eminem"}, "country": {"United states","England"}} 
print(dictionnary['dog'])
```

Comment: OK. I think I didnt explain myself properly. I would like to do this from the wordnet corpus so Id like to get the alternative words from this corpus. Is this doable?